# Cannot run GUI applications as root

Tags: permissions, root

I cannot run GUI applications such as gedit, synaptic as a root. I have tried many ways to run.

1. I have tried `xhost +localhost`
2. Used `gksudo` instead of `sudo`
3. `export DISPLAY=desktop:0`
   None of these work. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit.
   Whenever I run applications as root, I get error as follows:-

> No protocol specified
> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
> (gedit:3236): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:05:08.362: cannot open display: :0

Comment: Are you running X-Server or Wayland? Try X-Server

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -H gedit filename`?

Comment: I would not be able to do so because the error is solved. Its just that I cannot accept my own answer again until tomorrow. Btw, thanks for you reply. If anyone else gets the error they can try this method also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @kanehekili. I am using wayland only right now. I searched for switching to xorg from wayland and there I found [the solution](https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/).

I simply ran `xhost +si:localuser:root` and got the permissions back. Don`t know why I did not find any one use this command.

.